# meta chat rooms broken

Tags: support, bug, chat, login, openid

using google chrome on windows 7

I go to the following url

http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta

Even when logged in I get the following display which includes the link to login at the bottom

[image: chat room]

When I click on the link [logged in](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/login?returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fchat.meta.stackoverflow.com%2frooms%2f89%2ftavern-on-the-meta) I get the following screen

[image: add login]

I click on "Add login using google" it takes me back to the first screenshot. If i click on the [chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/) at the bottom it shows the following picture of a cat

[image: a cat]

I am able to go to the chat rooms at the following link without problems

https://chat.stackexchange.com/

But the following links result in the error page

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/
http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/

Using incognito mode in chrome makes no difference

Also using a different browser makes no differene

I tried creating a new account and I was able to access the chat rooms without error, but after merging that new account into my existing account the same problem came back.

I used a different open id provider with the new account, and after the merge I deleted my previous open id providers from the account, but this made no difference.

Comment: You should decide if you report the bug in chat or ask for adding video feature request. You can't have them both in the same post.

Comment: Which web browser? Which version ?

Comment: Can you join other room in Meta? Can you join chat in other sites, e.g. gaming? What happens if you browse in Incognito mode and try to login then chat?

Answer (score 7):

I can't reproduce anything about your redirect issue. The URL does get redirected, and it's *supposed* to get redirected, but I do not experience any errors with loading the chat page.

---

As far as adding a video to your profile: no you can't do that, and they will never allow you to do that. If you want, post a link to the video. But they will *never* support users embedding videos directly into their profile. That would just be annoying.

Comment: awww, man. You are just anti-cat! ... So am I, but I'm just sayin'

Comment: check your error logs

Comment: @Alex this user is a moderator, not a developer so he can't access the error logs. We'll need a dev to take a look.